# Scroll overflow issue with fixed element

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm trying to have a scroll overflow-y in my chatbox.
The thing is; I got a header to the chatbox too which is being overflown by the chat content before it is being scrollable.
I want it to stop overflowing before the `<div class="header">Social Chat</div>` so that it is never being overlapped.

Also; right now the content never gets scroll-able - I have no idea why.
Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FcEdx/

Comment: y dont u put overflowscroll for your message wrapper..?

Comment: @VivekVikranth
Doing so changes nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/FcEdx/9/

i modified the css as follows

```
.header
    {
        position: absolute;  
        z-index: 2;
        width: 100%;
    }
.chat-messages-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is great!
One thing though; would it be possible to make it so it's scrolled to the bottom on the page load through css? Or would that have to be done through JS?

Comment: yes you can achieve that with JS by appending the new message div at the end every time.
do mark this answer if it helped

Comment: Ahh thanks! One final question: I see that if I limit the number of messages to, say 2 (and keep the screen at full resolution). The send message box get's pushed up from the bottom. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: use auto height for the wrapper and not 95%;

Comment: You're a freaking wizard! Thank you so much!
EDIT: When I put auto height it disables the scrolling - what's the issue here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FcEdx/12/

change the height of the widget as you wish and change the positions of the wrapper and header to relative